# Show pointwise convergence of this piecewise function.

Tags: real-analysis, pointwise-convergence

My textbook is making an example of how uniform convergence of sequences of functions is important. As and important the author shows that, in general, *pointwise* convergence does not preserve some desired properties (when the sequence of functions is compared its limiting function $f$). Here's the example sequence: let $f_n(x)$ be defined, for $n \geq 2$ by

$$f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
n^2x,& 0 \leq x \leq 1/n \\
-n^2(x -\frac{2}{n}), &1/n \leq x \leq 2/n \\
0, &\text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

The author claims that clearly the the area under the piecewise defined curve is $1$ for all $n \geq 2$. I understand this and agree, and have shown this simply by appealing to the geometric formula for the area of a triangle. But then the author claims that it can be shown by the reader that $ f_n \to 0 $ so that

$$\int_0^1 f(x)\,  dx = 0 \neq 1 = \lim\int_0^1 f_n(x) \, dx$$

But I disagree with the author. I do not believe that $f_n \to 0$.

---

Suppose $f_n \to  0$, then for $\epsilon = 1$ and for each $x \in [0, \frac{2}{n}]$ there exists some $K \in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$|f_n(x) - 0 | < 1 \, , \, \, \forall n \geq K$$

Which considering the first part of the defined sequence we can shorten our interval to $x \in [0, \frac{1}{n}]$. So we have

$$n^2x < 1 \, , \, \, \forall n \geq K$$

This is only true when $x = 0$, so the statement is a contradictory as far as I can tell.

---

I don't know much about Dirac sequences but this strikes me as one. And if I recall correctly their limiting function value is infinite. Which is what I think I'm seeing here. So, I'm probably wrong (normally am versus the text), but what am I missing?

Comment: The way you've defined $f_n$ appears to involve a contradiction. Is the first formula supposed to apply when $x\le 1/n$, perhaps, and not $2/n$?

Comment: do you mind sharing which textbook is this from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a confusion about the quantifiers.

Suppose $(f_n)_n$ converges to $0$ pointwise. This means that, for every *fixed* $x$, we have
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x) = 0\tag{1}
$$
Setting $\varepsilon = 1$ as you did, this would require that

> there exists $K_x \geq 0$ such that, for every $n\geq K_x$, $$\lvert f_n(x)\rvert \leq 1$$

Note that $K$ depends on $x$ (which is why I explicitly denoted it $K_x$, to make this explicit to the reader's eye). But this is true: indeed, taking $K_x = \frac{1}{\lvert x\rvert +1}$ (for instance), we have that if $n\geq K_x$ then $x > 2/n$, and therefore $f_n(x)=0$. So (1) is not contradicted.

Comment: It was a combination of quantifier mix up and the fact that I didn't consider how the function becomes zero when x > 2/n.

Comment: @Zduff Indeed... now, in terms of uniform convergence we have $\lVert f_n\rVert_\infty = n$ for every $n$ (since $f_n(1/n)=n$), so uniform convergence is out of the picture.

Comment: How do you get $x > 2/n$ from that? All I get from the inequality is that $x \geq \frac{1 - n}{n}$

Answer (score 2):

I think there is something wrong with the definition you take of pointwise convergence of the sequence of functions.

Pick any point $x$ (different from $0$). Now, we want to show that $f_n(x)\rightarrow 0$. But this is quite easy: as soon as $2n>x$, then $f_n(x)=0$.

Now, note that $f_n(0)=0\forall n$. So that, for each $x$ in the interval $f_n(x)=0$.

Comment: How does 2n > x imply $f_n(x) = 0$? I'm assuming we're somehow supposed to get the inequality $x > \frac{1}{2n}$, but I don't see it how